# how to pass page as parameter to the webmethod via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

The following is my webmethod which is having page as parameter. I dont know how to pass the argument from javascript. below script is what i have put in my javscript. Please someone guide me.

Webmethod:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
Public Shared Function setpfdetails(ByVal pg As Page, ByVal pfid As String, ByVal uid As String)
    pg.Session.Add("hcur", pfid)
    pg.Session.Add("mtm", uid)
End Function
```

JavaScript:

```
PageMethods.setpfdetails(this,'Pf00109','5421',OnSuc,OnErr);
```

By this code my page got struck.

Please someone guide me how to pass the "Page" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do so.

But, from what I can gather, I guess you are trying to access your session or you are trying to store something to it. You do not need the page object for this. Besides you cannot use a page instance in a static method (web method). If you type `this` inside it (*`this`* referring the the aspx page), you'll learn the problem. And when talking about web methods (which are similar to web service methods - asmx) page instances don't make sense.

Sessions are logically tied to the http request, and not the aspx page as such. You can access it via the HttpContext object.

```
Dim oValue as Object = HttpContext.Current.Session[key]
```

You can also set a session value likewise.

Comment: I tried this in javascript   HttpContext.Current.Session["hcur"]="ss"; but not working

Comment: this has to be done from server side. I suppose your confusion is because I wrote c# code.